# How to create custom field in Product edit page (admin) Prestashop

Tags: product, admin, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to create a custom field called "vend id" in product page (Admin).

I also need to store some data in it.

I am not sure how to create field in it, though i have manually created fields in "_attribute" & "_product" table.

Any hint how to create it & store data in it ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

if the id of the seller is related to the id of the product, create the column in the table *_product*

if the seller's id is related to the combination of a product, i.e. the reference, then create the column in the table _attribute

It all depends on whether a seller sells a product and the combinations of that product.

Comment: @newphpdev In your case, how do you focus or relate the id of the seller to the products or how do you plan to do it?
depending on the case the idea seems interesting

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have created a column "vend id" in the products table(i.e _product ). now i will save data in it for each product.

Comment: @newphpdev Give me five! Good job!